# why dc machines have double layer winding?

Tags: dc-motor, electric-machine

why do dc machines always have double layer winding?is it possible to create a single layered winding dc machine?

More generic Question: Can anyone explain the logical evolution of dc machine from the prototype (single coil) to the actual double layer-distributed winding case?

Usually in text books they use single coil to explain the principle of operation and suddenly jump to parallel paths-multiple commutator segments-double layer closed winding case .Single coil doesn't have any parallel paths and i doubt whether it is closed too.What is the logic behind the actual implementation of a dc machine and how can it be explained as progressive evolution of the simple case?
Please note I understand the reason for use of distributed winding(more no:of windings in series and hence less ripple) and to a fair extent the working of actual implementation as well.What bothers me is "can i have  a dc machine with single layer, with any no: of parallel path(can it be one?),closed or un-closed winding for achieving the same emf?".

Also i'm concerned about the conceptual understanding.I tried theoretically to extend the single coil case to 2 coils in perpendicular connected in series.But i couldn't find a suitable commutator connection which will give me the required o/p(sum of their emfs).The only possible way was to go for double layer-closed form winding(which makes it 4 coils).I was not sure of this and wanted to confirm this.

Comment: Do you mean "motor" and not "machine"?

Comment: It seems you have answered this yourself in that lots of windings allows for capturing each most closely around its peak, which decreases overall output ripple.  Otherwise it's not clear what you mean by "single layer".  A diagram might clarify.

Comment: @Scott i meant 'dc machine' in general.

Comment: @ScottSeidman machine is the correct label since every electrical machine can be made to generate and motor. Yes specific design implementations do lend a a certain construction to be more optimal to motoring than generation (and vica versa) BUT that doesn't change the fact all are capable of generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double layer windings are the most widely used class of windings. Though both lap and wave types are possible, because of inherent problems of a wave windings, it is now an accepted practice to use the lap type for double layer ac windings. Double layer windings fall into two main classes depending upon the value of SSP-integral slot winding when SPP is an integer and fractional slot winding when SPP is a fractional number. To meet the requirement of symmetry among phases, the number of slots phase (S/3) must be a whole number.

Double layer windings in open slots have the following advantages over single layer windings in semi-closed slots.

1. Ease in manufacture of coils and lower cost of winding
2. Less number of coils are required as spare in the case of winding repairs
3. Fractional slot winding can be employed
4. Fractional pitch coil can be used

Answer (score 0):

Physical size of the device.

You wind a coil because you want to create a magnetic field by running a current through the coil.  The field strength is determined primarily by the amount of current doing loop-de-loops, times the number of loop-de-loops it makes, around the coil's reference axis.  If you want a stronger field, you increase the current, or you increase the number of loop-de-loops (traditionally "turns"), or both.

On a single-layer coil, adding turns adds length, and it can for some machines get unwieldy.  That's when you start doing multiple layers.  Instead of doubling the length of the coil, you can wrap a second layer of turns, and have it be the same length and just a little bit thicker.